# Formula to Search multiple multi line cells for items in column A and replace with items with values in column next to it

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuPAT.png)

If you look at the image above you will see example data.
I am looking to write VBA code or a formula that will search this data and perform a find and replace accross the whole sheet.

I have column 1, multiple multi line cells with line breaks. With multiple values, some duplicates some not. No specific order or length to the values.

I want to search Column 1 for the values found in column 3 and then if they are seen replace them with the values next to it in column 2. While maintaing the line break structure and format that they are currently in.

EXAMPLE DATA
| Column 1 |
|"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
UCSCUS1
UCSCUS2
UCSCUS3
UCSCUSWK1
UCSCUSWK2
MGUS1
MGUS2
PHUS1
PHUS2
WYUS1
WYUS2
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5
ERUS1
MPLW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 2
MPLW VC US 3
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
SJN US 4
BEUS1
FKUS1
BKUS1
ANDUS1
HIUS1
WWH US1
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
GHUS3
MICUS2
MICUS1
WBWW VC US 2"
"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
UCSCUS1
UCSCUS2
UCSCUS3
UCSCUSWK1
UCSCUSWK2
MGUS1
MGUS2
PHUS1
PHUS2
WYUS1
WYUS2
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5
ERUS1
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
WWH US1
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
MPLW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 2
MPLW VC US 3
WBWW VC US 1
SJN US 4
FKUS1
BEUS1
BKUS1
ANDUS1
HIUS1
GHUS3
MICUS2
MICUS1
WBWW VC US 2"
"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
UCSCUS1
UCSCUS2
UCSCUS3
UCSCUSWK1
UCSCUSWK2
MGUS1
MGUS2
PHUS1
PHUS2
WYUS1
WYUS2
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5
ERUS1
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
WWH US1
WWH US2
WWH US3
MPLW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 2
WBWW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 3
BEUS1
BKUS1
FKUS1
ANDUS1
HIUS1
GHUS3
MICUS2
MICUS1
WBWW VC US 2"
"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
UCSCUS1
UCSCUS2
UCSCUS3
UCSCUSWK1
UCSCUSWK2
MGUS1
MGUS2
PHUS1
PHUS2
WYUS1
WYUS2
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5
ERUS1
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
WWH US1
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
MPLW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 2
MPLW VC US 3
WBWW VC US 1
GHUS3
MICUS2
MICUS1
WBWW VC US 2"
"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3"
"SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
SJO US2
SJO US3
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
ZZSJO US1
WWH US1
MICUS2
MICUS1
4827006"
"WYUS4
PHUS1
RHUS1
SHUS4
UCUSATC1
UCUSATC2
HIUS1
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
SJO US2
SJO US3
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
WWH US1
GHUS3
MICUS2
EICUS2
EICUS1
MICUS1
4827006"
"SJN US 2
SJN US 3
SJO US2
SJO US3
ZZSJO US1
WWH US1
UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
MGUS1
MGUS2
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5"
"UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS3
UUUS4
URUS1
URUS2
URUS3
UCSCUS1
UCSCUS2
UCSCUS3
UCSCUSWK1
UCSCUSWK2
MGUS1
MGUS2
PHUS1
PHUS2
WYUS1
WYUS2
GHUS1
GHUS2
GHUSSP
RSCCUS1
RSCCUS2
RHUS1
RHUS2
SHUS1
SHUS2
SHUS5
ERUS1
SJN US 1
SJN US 2
SJN US 3
SJO US2
SJO US3
WWH US2
WWH US3
WWH US4
MPLW VC US 1
MPLW VC US 2
WBWW VC US 1
ZZSJO US1
WWH US1
MPLW VC US 3
GHUS3
MICUS2
EICUS2
EICUS1
MICUS1"
"UCSCUSV1
UCSCUSV2"
"SHUS4
RHUS1
WYUS4
SJN US 4
WWH US1"

Column 2 |
4827143
4827144
4827145
4827146
4827147
4827096
4827098
4827150
4827151
4827152
4827153
4827154

Column 3 |
UCCIUSR1
UCSCUSV1
UCSCUSWK2
UCUS1
URSONO
URUS1
URUS3
URWHSUS1
UUUS1
UUUS2
UUUS4
UUVAS1

Tried regular find and replace. Takes to long for the amount of data I have and hard to find errors.

Comment: Please add Table as HTML or better formatted. It looks really messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short sample based on your data:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A1&CHAR(10),CHAR(10),,1),E:E,D:D,"Not Found"))
```

You can also choose to do this for the whole range at once:

[image]

Formula used:

```
=LET(x,CHAR(10),MAP(A1:A2,LAMBDA(y,TEXTJOIN(x,,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(y&x,x,,1),E:E,D:D,"Not Found")))))
```

Comment: That first formula worked amazing! thanks so much, the not found message will save me hours of troble shooting.

Answer (score 2):

### Replace Delimited Substrings (`BYROW`)

[image]

```
=LET(dlData,$A$2:$A$6,slData,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$13,svData,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$13,
    cDelimiter,CHAR(10),IgnoreEmpty,1,
BYROW(dlData,LAMBDA(dlCell,
    LET(drData,TEXTSPLIT(dlCell,cDelimiter,,IgnoreEmpty),srData,XLOOKUP(drData,slData,svData),
        TEXTJOIN(cDelimiter,IgnoreEmpty,IFERROR(srData,drData))))))
```